# PowerShell and CSVs

Tags: csv, powershell

Good afternoon. I was hoping I might be able to get some assistance with some PowerShell that I'm scripting for maintaining a CSV file. The biggest problem with this file is that the date formatting changes through the system that adds to the file. My aim is to be able to run this script, have it change all of the dates to MM/dd/yyyy, sort oldest to newest (by date), and then search for duplicate addresses and leave the oldest.

I've got a little bit of a start, but I'm kind of stuck. I'm also doing a lot of (what I believe is) a lot of unnecessary file creation, and overly complicating these things. I'm new to PowerShell, and really scripting in general.

Here's what my data looks like (note the first line does not have quotes, and the output should stay the same). It's a txt file, but read like a CSV.

```
dev_address,date_added,comments,user_id,dev_name
"00:01:02:03:04:0a","05/19/2014","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0b","05/19/2014","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0c","05/19/2013","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0d","2015/7/8","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0e","2016/06/03","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
```

Here's what I've written so far:

```
$devList = Import-Csv .\TestFile.txt

$a = Get-Content .\TestFile.txt -TotalCount 1

Add-Content -Path '.\foo2.txt' -Value "$a"

$countList = -1

ForEach($devList in $devList)
    {
        $devMAC = $devList.dev_address
        $devDate = $devList.date_added
        $devComm = $devList.comments
        $devUser = $devList.user_id
        $devMName = $devList.dev_name

        $devDate = ([datetime]($devDate)).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')

        Add-Content -Path '.\foo2.txt' -Value """$devMAC"",""$devDate"",""$devComm"",""$devUser"",""$devMName"""
    }

Import-Csv '.\foo2.txt' | Sort-Object {[datetime]$_.date_added} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation '.\foo3.txt'
```

Now I know this is messy. So I'll kind of try to explain what I'm doing. Importing the CSV file. Saving the first line (headers) of the CSV file to a variable so I can pop it into the final file unaltered, later. Next, importing the data for each record to variables so they can be input into the final file. I sort of got the date thing figured out. That seems to change the dates to the correct format, then that 2nd to last line writes it to a file for every entry in $devList. The last line is importing that 2nd file, sorting by date and exporting to a 3rd final file. Mostly redundant for troubleshooting purposes. Wasn't planning on having 3 files.

What's the best way to import the data, format the dates to MM/dd/yyyy, sort by oldest to newest, then remove duplicate records based on dev_address (but keep the oldest record), then export to a new file including CSV headers with no quotes?

Thank you in advance :-)

EDIT:

Sorry I should've included desired output. Say I have this file:

```
dev_address,date_added,comments,user_id,dev_name
"00:01:02:03:04:0a","05/19/2014","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0a","06/05/2014","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0c","04/20/2013","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0d","2015/7/8","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0e","2016/06/03","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
```

This is my desired output:

```
dev_address,date_added,comments,user_id,dev_name
"00:01:02:03:04:0c","04/20/2013","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0a","05/19/2014","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0d","07/08/2015","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0e","06/03/2016","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
```

As you can see dates fixed and ordered, redundant dev_address removed and oldest retained. Top line stays intact.

Comment: If you could manually form an example of your expected output (instead of us having to parse the verbiage), it would help if you could [edit] that into the question to make it easier.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the response. I edited my original post to illustrate my goal.

Comment: Got it.  Now, this brings me to a few questions you may want to consider clarifying: 1) Your original data set could be formatted in **several possible date/time formats?**  Do you have a 'known' set of possibilities, or do we need to be prepared to handle ANY format, or give up?  2)  In your example output, you kept the **oldest** MAC address that was redundant.  Is that right?   From your standpoint, I can understand why you did several run-throughs in multiple files, now.  :-(  Yikes.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it. Unfortunately, yes, the data set could contain multiple date formats. To be honest, I guess I haven't seen anything besides yyyy/MM/dd though. It would be nice to be able to handle anything though. I'd like to keep the oldest MAC that was redundant. Okay, so maybe I wasn't that far off?

I was thinking about importing the data into an array and modifying so I wouldn't have so many "temp" files, then writing back to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for.. you were VERY close on your own. :)  Your final output will be in `output.txt`.

The top row (headers) are encapsulated with double quotes.  Please consider sticking to this, as it will create a universal 'csv' format between different cmdlets and/or other processes so they recognize the CSV file as universal.

**EDIT**: I did the sort in the wrong order earlier, I've adjusted it:

```
$devices = Import-CSV 38488676.csv

foreach ($device in $devices)
{
    $date = $device.date_added -as [DateTime];
    $device.date_added = $date.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
    #this foreach could all be done in one line by itself...
    #but it's easier to visualize and understand when broken out more
}

$devices | Sort-Object {$_.date_added -as [datetime]} | Sort dev_address -Unique | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation output.txt
```

This gives me the following output:

```
"dev_address","date_added","comments","user_id","dev_name"
"00:01:02:03:04:0c","4/20/2013","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0a","6/5/2014","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0d","7/8/2015","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
"00:01:02:03:04:0e","6/3/2016","NIC Manufacturer = Microsoft","bob","comp1"
```

Comment: You are AWESOME! This worked great! The last line I switched the Sort-Object and Sort around since it seemed to be sorting by MAC address instead of date.

Thanks again, I really appreciate this help!

Comment: Careful - What you want to be sure is that you're doing the sort on the `dev_address` LAST, and with the `-Unique` switch.  That's what will remove duplicates.  This is also why I edited it earlier, because the order you do it in will affect if you keep the oldest or newest one... either way, I'm glad this worked out.  ;-)